# Finding elements far from mean

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I'm designing a program to segment a scanned document into individual characters (for character recognition). When I have a list of segmented characters, I know their dimensions and by extension their areas. I want to remove elements from this list which are well outside what is expected. For example, I might have these elements:

$$e(area) = 0(164), 1(172), 2(188), 3(160), 4(12), 5(158), 6(160), 7(4)$$

From this list, elements $4$ and $7$ have areas so small compared to the rest that they can be removed. Elements like these might be noise accidentally segmented into a character, or something like a pen slipped when writing.

What methodology would be best to eliminate elements from a list which are so far from the mean?

I cannot use "remove lowest % of elements" as this can remove valid elements (eg. in the absence of supersmall elements), nor can I use "remove elements with smaller than n area", as the area of characters can vary wildly.

Can standard deviation be used in this manner? Does that work how I think it works? "remove elements outside 3 standard deviations from the mean"? In my testing, these supersmall elements comprise roughly 0~1.2% of any given document.

Comment: This is a tough problem, you seem to disallow all easy & obvious criteria. The standard deviation is the way to go ... I did a similar thing with accelerometer data, trying to find the stable & least traumatic parts of an event. I did the while within a while loop until the only remianing data was within a threshold value of the "new" standard deviation ... You should try something similar ... but you need to experiment to find the threshold value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the boxplot method of identifying outliers. 
Begin by finding the 'five-number summary' of your data: these are (in order
of increasing size) the minimum, lower-quartile $Q_1$, median, upper-quartile $Q_3,$ and maximum. The quartiles and the median cut the *sorted* sample into
four 'chunks' of approximately equal numbers of values. The 'interquartile
range' is $\text{IQR} = Q_3 - Q_1.$

**Boxplot outlier rules.** An *outlier rule* designates as 'outliers'
values below $Q_1 - k\text{IQR}$ and above $Q_2 + k\text{IQR},$ for some
appropriately chosen $k.$ These boundaries, called 'fences' are used to find outliers, but are not explicitly shown in a boxplot.

Commonly chosen values are $k = 1.5$ (for
so-called 'possible outliers') and $k = 3$ (for 'probable outliers').
Also, $k = 2.25$ has been suggested because, for normal data, it tends
to tag as outliers approximately the same percentage of values across
small and moderate numbers of observations $n.$

**Data for an example.** I may be on dangerous ground here, but I am guessing that the sample
size of your example ($n= 8$) is much smaller than in a realistic example
and the the proportion of 'contamination' with bad values (25%)
is larger than in a realistic example. So I will use simulated data
that are 90% from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 170,\, \sigma = 12)$ with 10%
contamination ffom $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 15,\, \sigma = 2).$ Here are $n = 100$
such values. I have rounded them to integers, sorted them, and found
the quartiles and the interquartile range IQR:

```
x.ok = rnorm(90, 170, 12);  x.out = rnorm(10, 15, 2);  x = round(c(x.ok, x.out))
sort(x);  quantile(x);  IQR(x)
x
##  [1]  12  13  14  15  15  15  16  17  17  17 141 145 146 146 148 149 150 150 152 153
## [21] 155 156 157 160 160 160 162 162 163 164 164 164 164 164 165 165 166 166 167 167
## [41] 168 168 168 168 168 169 170 170 170 171 171 171 171 172 172 172 173 173 173 173
## [61] 174 174 174 174 175 176 176 177 177 177 177 178 178 178 178 178 178 178 179 179
## [81] 179 180 181 182 182 184 184 184 185 185 186 187 189 190 190 191 191 193 196 203
quantile(x);  IQR(x)
##  0%  25%  50%  75% 100%  # five number summary 
##  12  160  171  178  203 
##  18                      # IQR

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
boxplot(x, col="red", main="Outlier Rule: 1.5 IQR")  # k=1.5 is default
boxplot(x, range=2.25, col="blue2", main="Outlier Rule: 2.25 IQR")
boxplot(x, col="green2", range=3, main="Outlier Rule: 3 IQR")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

For my fake data the contamination is sufficiently rare (10%) and extreme (good values averaging about 7 standard deviations above bad ones)
that boxplots with all three criteria (choices of $k$) correctly label
the ten 'contamination' values as outliers.

Notice that the 'boxes' in boxplots extend from $Q_1$ to $Q_3$ (height IQR). The 'whiskers' extend upward and downward to the most
extreme non-outlier values. Outliers are plotted individually.

You need to know that boxplot criteria do identify some extreme values
in pure normal data (no contamination) as outliers. In samples of size
$n = 100:$ on average, almost 1 per sample, for $k = 1.5;\;$ about 0.05, for $k=2.25;\;$
about 0.003, for $k=3.\;$ So use $k = 3$ when possible.

---

**Breakdown.** By contrast, if the 'good' observations are from $\mathsf{Norm}(150,15),$
and 20% contaminated with observations from  $\mathsf{Norm}(35,5),$
then the criterion with $k=3$ begins to 'break down', possibly not identifying
all of the 'bad' observations.

[image]

For your data, you might want to explore which value of $k$ seems to do the
best job of itentifying 'contamination' values. However, for the small sample
of eight values, boxplots do not detect the values 4 and 12 as outliers;
the contamination is so prevalent as to stretch the IQR to the point where
the criterion is useless.

---

*Note:* If you do not find that boxplot outlier rules 'work' to find outliers
in your kind of data, here is another method that is sometimes used: 
(a) Remove one value at a time from the sample; (b) find the average $a$ and
standard deviation $s$ of the remaining $n-1$ values; (c) discard the 'removed'
value if it is not within the interval $a \pm 2s$; (d) iterate for all $n$
observations. (If you use mean and SD of the whole sample, they are distorted
by bad observations, and results won't reject enough bad observations.)

Also, you may want to read some of the literature on methods of 'exploratory data analysis' (EDA) and 'robust estimation'
to see if you can find more suitable methods.

However, if contamination values are too close to legitimate ones or if
the percentage of contamination is high, it will be very difficult to find
any method that can identify all or almost all contamination values.

Comment: For an example document of 168 characters, 2 are found to be "garbage" and need to be removed. The mean area for this population is 22,389 and the two pieces of garbage have areas 70 and 6 to give an idea. Beyond the outliers, the range of character areas are 6,708 - 38,039. In testing using a standard deviation to eliminate garbage, values under $2\sigma$ less than the mean seemed to work.

Comment: OK fine, but for _uncontaminated_ normal data, using $\mu - 2\sigma$ will tag an avg of 2.5 false 'outliers' in a sample of size 100, compared to less than one with the boxplot $k=1.5$ rule and almost none with $k = 3.$ There are tradeoffs.

Comment: Which is worse: keeping a bad one or tossing a good one? What about using one of these 'automatic' rules (boxplot or SD) only on elements for which recognition is problematic or questionable?